# Как в Visual Studio 2015 избавить проект от персональной информации?

Tags: visual-studio

Обратил внимание на то, что проект, созданный в Visual Studio имеет много персональной информации. Например пути к месторасположению файла проекта, имя подключенного Team Foundation сервера. Возможно что-то еще.

Есть задача опубликовать исходные коды проекта, но таким образом, чтобы никакой информации о разработчике и той станции на которой велась разработка, не передавались. Тоесть нужно сделать проект обезличенным.

Есть ли способ это сделать? Любые идеи?

Comment: Информация о точном пути к исходникам лежит даже в Майкрософтовских pdb :)

Comment: В любом случае, вся информация есть в текстовом виде в `.xxproj.`. Вы можете заглянуть внутрь и увидеть, что реально передаётся (и удалить вручную, если что).

Comment: @VladD Допустим я отредактирую .xxproj. А как быть с pdb?

Comment: А их просто не выкладывайте :) Если вы даёте исходники, любой может построить у себя библиотеку, и получит PDB  с путями к его файлам, как ему и нужно.

Comment: @VladD OK. pdb, xxproj, sln - все, больше нигде нет?

Comment: А это по идее всё, что вы выкладываете. `*.cs`, `*.xaml`, `*.cpp`, `*.h`, `*.vb` под вашим контролем, *.*proj вы просмотрели, в `*.sln` ничего нет (но загляните на всякий случай, а то вдруг я ошибся?)